# Not able to fetch the IP address in Node JS from the client side in the AWS server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node js and I want to fetch the IP address of the client device in AWS server.
I have two instances of AWS server So the code is working fine with one instance but when I upload this to another instance it is giving me wrong IP as "ffff:127.0.0.0".
Do I need to do anything extra?

I am using following code:

```
var ipAddress = req.headers['cf-connecting-ip'] || req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Comment: If you are behind a load balancer the `x-forwarded-for` header should contains a list of IPs [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: @GabrielBleu What exactly I have to do? I am getting 127.0.0.0 so how to get public IP

Comment: I have treid this but still not working                                                        
     var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
     req.connection.remoteAddress || 
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null);

Answer (score 0):

```
const clientIp = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress
```

This works for me on my AWS ec2 instance.

Comment: could you just elaborate your situation and if you don't mind show us your code, that would be helpful for us to find the solution. I think proxy server or vpn is causing the issue, so if you don't know about proxy server, see here http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-server and vpn is somewhat similar to proxy(just google it)

Comment: I am using above line only for fetching IP ADDRESS ,

Comment: Actually i have two instance and it is working on one instance andin second instance it is creating problem